# FBSDKGraphRequest: How to cast Facebook work experience data in Swift to UILabel

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, casting

I am able to retrieve and display name, birthday, email, and picture.

I am able to retrieve the work data as it prints just fine.

My question is how I am able to display something specific like employer name and position name in a label.

```
func showUserData()
        {
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, first_name, birthday, work, email, picture.type(large)"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
    {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
    }
        else
    {
        // Request firstname
        let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! NSString

        // Request birthdate
        let userBirthday : NSString = result.valueForKey("birthday") as! NSString

        // Request work info
        let userWork : NSArray = result.valueForKey("work") as! NSArray

        self.worklabel.text = "\(userWork)"
        print(userWork)

        // Convert String to NSDate
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyy"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(userBirthday as String)
        let birthday: NSDate = date!
        var now: NSDate = NSDate()
        var ageComponents: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Year, fromDate: birthday, toDate: now, options: [])
        var age: Int = ageComponents.year

        // Request profile picture
        let strPictureURL: String = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!
        self.namelabel.text = "\(userName), \(age)"
        self.image.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)!)!)

            }
            })
}
```